# Linear regression with mean and standard deviation instead of values of each repetition possible?

Tags: regression, linear

I have a question about a linear regression I would like to perform.

In my experiment I have two treatments and a control which have 4 repetitions of 20 genotypes each. I have performed linear regression on this data which worked fine. I wish to perform a linear regression on the differences between the treatments and the control as well (so for both treatments: y_difference = y_treatment - y_control). I would have to calculate this on a repetition level in order for the linear regression to function.

However, my experimental setup is a bit suboptimal due to infrastructural limitations. If I would have had a proper randomized blockdesign, it would have been no problem to match a treatment plot with a control plot. Within each block I then would have had a control plot and a plot for each treatment for every genotype. However, I dont have a proper randomized design. Each "block" only contains a single treatment.

[image]

In this simplified example I could potentially use rows or columns as blocking variable, but in my actual experiment I cannot.

What I can do is for every treatment-genotype combination calculate a mean and a standard deviation. Now my question is: Is that enough information to run a linear regression with and if so, how do I do that in R?

Thanks!